# Low Water Pressure on kitchen sink, but using the Spray nozzle "fixes" it

Tags: kitchens, water-pressure, kitchen-sink

When I run the kitchen sink (Hot, Cold or Both) I get fairly low water pressure. However if I use the spray nozzle (even for just a few seconds) the pressure returns to normal, at least until next time I use the sink.

The water pressure isn't super low (it's not a trickle) but enough to be noticable. Is there something simple I can check to fix this issue?

Comment: Something's worn out or crudded up in the faucet mechanism. Without knowing anything about your hardware, all I can suggest is to clean it or replace parts. Maybe revise to add more detail.

Comment: Perhaps there's a partial blockage in a faucet line and running the spray nozzle sucks it back, while running the faucet suck it forward to partially block faucet flow again. First, remove the faucet aerator and flush out the faucet (forwards). Then, disconnect the cold water supply line end and direct it into a bucket (after turning off the shutoff valve for it), set the faucet mixer to warm (hot and cold together) and turn on the faucet, expecting water to flow back out the cold supply line and hopefully flushing out any blockage item (back flushing).

Answer (score 2):

That sounds like a problem in the diverter valve that reduces tap flow when the spray is in use. These do wear out and/or accumulate mineral deposits. Unfortunately that isn't a well standardized part, so you'd have to look into what your particular manufacturer did and whether service/replacement parts are available. Mine is stuck the other way -- I get almost no diversion to the spray -- and I'm anticipating I'll just have to replace the entire tap if I want to fix it.